# Kubernetes HPA gets wrong current value for a custom metric

Tags: docker, kubernetes, autoscaling, google-kubernetes-engine

HPA status displays `132500m / 500` in a situation when the actual metric value is lower then `100/500` (according to the Prometheus).

```
$ kubectl get hpa -n frontend --context testing
NAME       REFERENCE              TARGETS                               MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
frontend   Deployment/streaming   50237440 / 629145600, 132500m / 500   2         5         2          4d
```

HPA manifest is:

```
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: streaming
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: streaming
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: redis_memory_used_rss_bytes
      targetAverageValue: 629145600
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: redis_db_keys
      targetAverageValue: 500
```

It should print normal results, like:

```
$ kubectl get hpa -n streaming --context streaming-eu
NAME       REFERENCE              TARGETS                               MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
frontend   Deployment/streaming   50237440 / 629145600, 87 / 500   2         5         2          4d
```

The problem is in that `132500m` value, which is wrong (Prometheus query reports a normal value). And as `HPA` didn't scale up on that metric, so it saw it's value somewhat different, I suppose.

Use [oliver006/redis_exporter](https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter) and it's metrics as a custom `Pod` metrics with HPA to reproduce this issue.

*Kubernetes version*:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", GitVersion:"v1.9.4-gke.1", GitCommit:"10e47a740d0036a4964280bd663c8500da58e3aa", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-13T18:00:36Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

*Cloud provider*:

```
GKE 1.9.4
```

Comment: Do you have any other Redis cache in your cluster except one which you want to use as the source of the metric for scaling?

Comment: nope, just these two pods of it in the separate namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is a metric conversion problem.

Here is a good [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57365#issuecomment-359467755) from the contributor on the related issue, but it's about the `http_requests` metric:

> if you look at the documentation for the Prometheus adapter, you'll see that all cumulative (counter) metrics are converted to rate metrics, since the HPA's algorithm in fundamentally incompatible with scaling on cumulative metrics directly (scaling on cumulative metrics directly doesn't make much sense in general).
>
> In your case, your http_requests_total is being converted into http_requests, so it will always show up as milli-requests from the metrics API when using the Prometheus adapter.

So, in your case, it is returning something like 132500 millirecords. Just divide value to 1000, and you will get the correct average value.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, mate, that makes sense. But, there's something that bothers me: it shows actual metric value from time to time, so that is strange in case it tries to convert it to millirecords. What do you think about it?

Comment: I can only guess that is the artifact of conversion in combination with calculation of the average value.

Comment: This is correct (source: I wrote much of the code in question).  For most of its numeric values that might need decimal places, Kubernetes uses a special type called `Quantity`.  Instead of displaying things as a decimal, it will display with SI suffixes.  For instance, 1.5 becomes 1500m.  When Kubernetes displays a quantity, it will tend to use milli-units if there would be a decimal point, and plain units otherwise.  So, if it had to display 500 on the dot, it would just display 500, but if it's 500.5, it would display 500500m.  They mean the same thing -- it's just a display issue.

Comment: @DirectXMan12 thank you again, I'll mark this correct.