# HPA Reports a different value for External Metric than endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, hpa

I'm trying to scale a deployment with an HPA using an external metric. The external metric is created from a metric in Prometheus and is exported using the Prometheus adapter.

When I hit the endpoint for the external metric, I get back the correct value so I believe that everything up to that point (metric generator, prometheus, prometheus adapter) is working correctly.

```json
kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/queues_idle_agent_count | jq
{
  "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "metricName": "queues_idle_agent_count",
      "metricLabels": {},
      "timestamp": "2023-03-24T17:24:52Z",
      "value": "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

7 is the correct value for how many idle agents I have.

However in my HPA this value is not shown:

```
❯ k describe hpa                                                                                         
Warning: autoscaling/v2beta2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler is deprecated in v1.23+, unavailable in v1.26+; use autoscaling/v2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler
Name:                                                buildkite-agent
Namespace:                                           default
Labels:                                              <none>
Annotations:                                         <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                   Fri, 24 Mar 2023 13:20:02 -0400
Reference:                                           Deployment/buildkite-agent
Metrics:                                             ( current / target )
  "queues_idle_agent_count" (target average value):  1 / 2
Min replicas:                                        3
Max replicas:                                        25
Deployment pods:                                     7 current / 7 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason               Message
  ----            ------  ------               -------
  AbleToScale     True    ScaleDownStabilized  recent recommendations were higher than current one, applying the highest recent recommendation
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound     the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from external metric queues_idle_agent_count(nil)
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange   the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age    From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----   ----                       -------
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  2m45s  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 7; reason: All metrics below target
```

With the interesting part being here:

```
Metrics:                                             ( current / target )
  "queues_idle_agent_count" (target average value):  1 / 2
```

My target value is 2, but its reporting the current value as 1 when its actually 7.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816994/kubernetes-hpa-gets-wrong-current-value-for-a-custom-metric) question related to my issue, but it seems like this problem was just a scaling issue, while mine is not due to scaling.

I'm unsure why the HPA is reporting the incorrect value.

`hpa.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: buildkite-agent
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: buildkite-agent
  minReplicas: 3
  maxReplicas: 25
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metric:
        name: queues_idle_agent_count
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the way the metric is passed is `value/n` where n is the minimum replicas and value is the value received from the metric.

This isn't the way I thought the metric was passed, but it is useable for this use case.